# bash: simplification of code block

Tags: bash

Is there any way of simplifying the following code block?

```
if [ -z "$a_variable" ]; then
  func "default-value"
else
  func $a_variable
fi
```

Ideally I'm looking for a one liner of doing the above.

Comment: The way the code is written right now is clearer than any one liner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just

```
func ${a_variable:-"default_value"}
```

The `${x:-defval}` syntax will return `$x` if it is defined and non-empty, `defval` otherwise.